# How to implement logistic regression deviance from scratch

Tags: regression, logistic, inference, scikit-learn, deviance

As a learning exercise, I'm trying to implement the deviance for logistic regression from scratch.

I understand the deviance to be:

> $\mathcal{L}_S - \mathcal{L}_M$, where $\mathcal{L}_s$ is equal to the likelihood of the saturated model (the ground truth values we're predicting) and $\mathcal{L}_m$ is equal to the values predicted by our logistic regression model under maximum likelihood estimation.

Deviance is therefore a measurement of the fit of the model -- of the "deviance" of the residuals.

Mathematically, the deviance is equal to:

> $-2 \sum_{i=1}^K [y_i \log({{\hat{p}_i} \over{y_i}}) + (1 - y_i) \log({{1 - \hat{p}_i} \over{1 - y_i}})]$

My Python implementation is the following, where I've multiplied by $-1$ and inverted the logits:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics

_X, _y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
X, y = [], []

for i in range(len(_y)):
    if _y[i] < 2:
        X.append(_X[i])
        y.append(_y[i])

clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0).fit(X, y)

def deviance(X, y, model):
    sums = []
    for (y_i, x_i) in zip(y, model.predict_proba(X)):
        if y_i == 0:
            rh = 2 * (1 - y_i)*log((1 - y_i)/ (1 - x_i[y_i]))
            lh = 0
        else:
            lh = 2 *(y_i * log(y_i / x_i[y_i]))
            rh = 0
        sums.append((lh + rh))
    return sum(sums)
```

In short, my understanding is the deviance is composed of left-hand and right-hand sides, where each side corresponds to the true Bernoulli outcome of the observation. One side should be "zereoed-out" because if $y_i = 0$, then the left-hand side is equal to zero. If $y_i = 1$, then the right-hand side is equal zero.

However, my deviance calculation does not match the deviance calculation from sklearn:

> `2 * metrics.log_loss(y, model.predict_proba(X), normalize=False)`

My calculation gives `394.967593909003`.

The sklearn value is about `4.5`.

Even if I average over my estimate, the result is still off: I get 3.94 vs. 4.52

What did I do wrong? It seems close but not quite right..

Comment: First when talking about Logistic model, we expect 2 categories and not more than 2. Iris dataset has 3 categories

Comment: That's facts. I copied the example from sklearn's LR page but in hindsight I should try another dataset. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

Comment: @KU99 I've updated the post to only include the first two classes in the Iris dataset.